# Is it possible to get an exponential capacitance curve from coded dip switch

Tags: capacitor, switches, capacitance, configuration

I have a capacitor that controls frequency for a specialty IC with the relationship

\$F \propto 1/C\$

I want to be able to get a number of frequencies in evenly spaced intervals. Currently I have a string of series capacitors some of which I short out with regular dip switches in a binary code to give 16 steps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rTLA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works as adding capacitors in series follows the relationship below giving linear steps.

\$ F \propto \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{2C} + \frac{1}{4C} +\frac{1}{8C} \$

To make it more intuitive to set the frequency for people who are not used to binary code I would like to use a coded rotary dip switch [such as this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1537857.pdf)

This means the switches are not all separate and have a common pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0z2xr.png)</sup>

Because of this the relationship is exponential and it is not possible to get even steps based on this circuit

\$ F \propto \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{C + 2C + 3C+ 4C}\$

---

TLDR

Is there a simple way to get evenly spaced frequency steps using a coded rotary dip switch, without needing too many more components.

Comment: Ummm - use different value capacitors?

Comment: Different values will still have the same problem of changing step size

Comment: Does your IC also have a resistor that controls current ?

Comment: I have two pins that it expects me to apply capacitance across

Comment: Four relays? Connect each output of the rotary switch to the coil of an SPST relay.

Comment: Rather than a coded rotary dip switch, perhaps a rotary selector.  Possibly a big one custom made with PCB technology like cheap voltmeters use.  Can you replace the IC with a version with a programming interface?  How big in value are the capacitors?  Air variable capacitors can be made with interesting plate shapes.

Comment: THat's not exponential

Comment: @Hugoagogo, applications requiring equi-spaced frequency intervals are a little unusual because in so many systems it's the _ratio_ between the frequencies that's important. e.g., on the musical scale each note is 12th root of 2 times the note below. (Twelve semitones = one octave => double the frequency.) Similarly, for a given Q (quality) factor the bandwidth of a filter will be proportional to the centre frequency. Old rotary dial lab oscillators and AM radio dials have unequal spacing for the same reason. Tell us more about your application and chip.

Comment: This is to select the excitation frequency of an LVDT Demodulator, as such the transducers come with a set/recommended excitation frequency, to minimize phase shift

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

The 4 relay idea from Tom C is one option.

Other then that, if using a group of relays is not practical, then an old fashion 16 position rotary switch could do the trick too.

You could create a similar capacitor string as in your first diagram using 16 equal value capacitors, (much easier then finding several specific values) then use the 16 position switch to connect to each of the 16 intersections within the string.  That would give you the "division" format you seem to need.

Low cost 12 position switches can be had from surplus dealers.

Comment: Yes they add together in a linear way giving linear capacitance steps, this gives non linear frequency steps

Comment: Where is the non-linear part?  Your equation says "proportional to" doesn't it?

Comment: Not really, it is proportionate to the inverse.

Comment: Made very clear http://tinyurl.com/n9og6tq

Comment: It could also be claimed that your Frequency intervals (per the list) are not "evenly" spaced, they are divisions (ratios), each step is a divide by n.

Comment: I thought of this but couldnt find any 10/16 pos switches small enough for PCB mount, and under 13x13mm or so.